# How to return values of a function performed on an object without modifying an object?

Tags: python, object, return

I am new to oop.  I am writing some code to modify an image and then perform a search function on that image looking for some specific features.  The search function will be used on multiple image types, which is why I made it part of the base class.  My issue is that the below function (search) returns my obj as a tuple, instead of returning the image for further 'processing'.  I need both image(object) and x, y values.

```
class image:
    def search(self, image):
        # Perform some search function
        return x, y # where x, y is the pixel location

class specific_image_type(image):
    def process(self, image):
        # process image
        return processed_image
    
    def search(self):
        return super().search(processed_image)
```

I could do something like this....however the object now has a tuple and and image in it.  Is there a better way to design this so the image is the returned object and x, y are returned separately?

```
  class image:
        def search(self, image):
            # Perform some search function
            return x, y, image
```

Comment: Well, that IS the way you return them separately.  Remember, when you're calling this, you can unpack the tuple:  `x, y, image = myimage.search( image2)`.

Comment: if you don't want to change the state of the class with some function, then don't. The technical way of structuring methods within a class for purpose has to do with @ classMethods and @ static methods https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/ but this is more to do with whether a method is called from an instance of some class, or from the class itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally use *attributes* to maintain state in a class instance:

```py
class image:
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image

    def search(self):
        # Perform some search function on self.image
        # ...
        return x, y

class specific_image_type(image):
    def process(self):
        # process self.image and store result in self.image
        # ...
```

Here it is not necessary to override the `search` method. The inherited one is fine.

Use like:

```py
img = specific_image_type(my_image)
img.process()
x, y = img.search()
```

Comment: thanks!  The last line is where my mistake was.  Makes sense now to unpack the returned tuple and not modify the object.